# using jQuery with Tailwindcss?

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js

I started using Tailwind recently and I ran into a problem that I had to write jquery code to show the elements for example or make some effects, etc...

So I wonder if there is, for example, a library or a specific add-on or anything that can save time **instead of writing jquery manually with Tailwind?**